# How to find all instances of a substring inside a nested dict that could contain more lists or lists of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a function that takes a substring and a dict as arguments and traverses said dict and finds all instances of the substring in the dict, no matter if its inside the key, or the value. It could also be inside a list thats the value of a key, so it should be really universal no matter the dict structure.

When found the whole string containing that substring should be replaced by another value. For that I already have a function that takes that string and looks up a corresponding id.

Where Im stuck is to replace the string if its one element of a list inside a value of the dict.

What I have so far looks like this:

```
def dict_extract(self, search_str: str, d: dict) -> None:
        if hasattr(d, "items"):
            for k, v in d.copy().items():
                if str(search_str) in k:
                    id_ = find_id(search_str)
                    d[id_] = d.pop(k)
                if isinstance(v, str) and str(search_str) in v:
                    id_ = find_id(search_str)
                    d[k] = d[k].replace(d[k], id_)
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    self.dict_extract(search_str, v)
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    for i in v:
                        if isinstance(i, dict):
                            self.dict_extract(search_str, i)
                        if isinstance(i, str):
                            # please replace the string inside the list
```

An example input dict:

```
d = {
            "level1": {
                "level2": {
                    "k1": "v1",
                    "k2": [
                        "{replaceme:test123}",
                        "{replaceme:test456}"
                    ]
                },
                "replaceme:test789": "blaaa"
            }
```

}

using the function like so: dict_extract("replaceme", d)
should replace all strings that contain "replaceme" with the looked up id of it.
In the end the original dict passed in should have the ids instead of the strings.

final dict:

```
    d = {
                "level1": {
                    "level2": {
                        "k1": "v1",
                        "k2": [
                            "id123",
                            "id456"
                        ]
                    },
                    "id789": "blaaa"
                }
}
```

As said this is just an example and the stucture could look different and the replaceme strings could be in any position there.

Comment: where do you lookup the id?

Comment: @umläute I have a seperate function that takes the name and does an api call to get the id, but didnt show it here because that part is already done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are mutable. Easiest is to replace by index. you can get this with `enumerate`

```
def dict_extract(self, search_str: str, d: dict) -> None:
        ...
                   for indx, item in enumerate(v):
                        if isinstance(item, dict):
                            self.dict_extract(search_str, item)
                        if isinstance(item, str):
                            v[indx] = <your new value>
```

You might have an easier time manipulating the dictionary as a string instead of as a Python structure?

The function below illustrates a straightforward replace. You could extend it with a regex that replaces everything between quotes " instead of just `old`.

```
import json
def replace_terms_in_dict(old, new, _dict):
    string = json.dumps(_dict)
    string = string.replace(old, new)
    _dict = json.loads(string)
    return _dict
```

Comment: thanks for the indepth answer, I will try implementing the first part, although I am really intreagued by the regex example. I suck at regex though so not sure if I could manage the complexity. I guess I would have to match the string first, lookup the id and then use the regex to replace anything inside the brackets for that string.